# Iterating over object updating properties equal to a dictionary

Tags: typescript

I have the following example object

```js
const example = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: 123,
  d: "1",
  e: "3",
  f: false,
};
```

and I have another one that works like a dictionary for some properties from `example`

```js
const dictionary = {
  d:{
    "1": "good",
    "2": "bad",
    "3": "perfect",
    "4": "terrible",
  },
  e:{
    "1": "big",
    "2": "small",
    "3": "huge",
  },
```

What I need is to iterate over `example` looking for properties that exist in `dictionary` and update it based on its value, so at the end I have this

```js
example = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: 123,
  d: "good",
  e: "huge",
  f: false
};
```

I have tried this

```js
for (const field of Object.keys(dictionary)) {
    if (field in example) {
       Object.assign(example, { [field]: dictionary[field][example[field]] });
    }
}
```

but I get a lot of index errors

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObject = Object.entries(example).reduce((changedObj, [key, val]) => {
   return { ...changedObj, [key]: dictionary?.[key]?.[val] ?? val }
}, {})

console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but TypeScript complains twice and it has a point.

First it complains about `dictionary[field]`. Depending on the value of `field`, the type of `dictionary[field]` is either an object with three properties or an object with four properties (and it probably can have more values). TypeScript cannot detect the type of `dictionary[field]` (because the possible values do not intersect) and decides that its type is `any`. Next `example[field]` is used as a property name of `dictionary[field]` but `any` does not have properties.

It also complains about `example[field]` because, again, its type cannot be determined. Depending on the value of `field`, the type of `example[field]` is `number`, `string` or `boolean`. Because these types have nothing in common, the detected type of `example[field]` is also `any` and it cannot be used as a property name.

The solution is simple: declare types for `example` and `dictionary` to let TypeScript know what do you want from it.

It is easy to describe the type of `dictionary`:

```js
const dictionary: Record<string, Record<string, string>> = {
  ...
};
```

It is easy to describe the type of `example` too...

```js
const example: Record<string, string | number | boolean> = {
  ...
};
```

... but this does not stop TypeScript complaining and it is right again: `example[field]` is used as a property name of `dictionary[field]` but a `boolean` value cannot be used as an index; only `string` and `number` are allowed as property names.

The solution is to explicitly declare `any` as the type of the values stored in `example`:

```js
const example: Record<string, any> = {
  ...
};
```

These types allows TypeScript to perform its code analysis.

Check them [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAuGAlOUAJwBMAeaIgSzAHMAaGJMATwD4YBeGAbwCgYTXACIAZiBDD6AmACMRspESkzguAIwAmAMzTBJEepWCcMYduMxRuUUgwQ40gL4BuPn1CRYJKsChVwJRZcAmJyShoGfEIQUgooajpGCLo2Dm5+fWxMwTMjEVoJEktBYU1hBSRivVzzCrM0OCJRQigSswAWeuEoJupZLEsnGpwc0vyzWSpadrLuiBQ7DFmLEQALAFdaOCHnNz5xIhgACk9oKyo4DBIYEFEYAHlZACtWgDoAazgWCGOfPwCYCCAEpgbwZIIqPdjqJLtcYDR4Mh0FgwWNco8Xu8kBAINMwMdEKhMI5eDAANqwq4kAC6uH+-kCRBYlLhtPJRJRcFZ1JpNJgTmBbgxTj4oo84AgICwbwwIFohORJKFQA).